# Can I use tokenInput with jQuery 3.1.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

Currently I've got a pretty basic setup that was working reliably until I updated my jQuery. I noticed that in the header of jquery.tokeninput.js there's a reference to jQuery 1.10.2 which was what I had before... Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Comment: there's no reference to jQuery 1.10.2 that I can see ... only `"jquery" : ">= 1.5.x"` ... 3.1.1 is > 1.5.x ... so there's a better than poor chance it will work

Comment: Weird. I'm getting this error: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." referencing jquery.tokeninput.js. I checked the URL but it's not really helpful...

Comment: that's a **warning** ... not an **error** ... is it your code, or the 4 year old tokeninput code that is causing that **warning**

Comment: Sorry just updated the comment.

Comment: are you using minimised tokeninput? if not, what line number is associated with the warning (if any) - there's nowhere in the latest (3 years old) tokeninput that tries synchronous xmlhttprequest ... so either it's your code doing it, or you have an old version of tokeninput

Comment: Hmm... That would make sense... This has been sitting around for awhile. The jquery.tokeninput.js file is what's generating the xml warning... Is that even part of tokeninput? It doesn't seem to show up on their downloads.

Comment: `jquery.tokeninput.js` is the one and only file you need to use tokeninput??~~

Comment: but, there's nothing in the **current** version of the code that would make any AJAX synchronous - do you make any AJAX calls with `async:false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137006/discussion-between-itchyspacesuit-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 0):

Okay so - it turns out that I had an old version of jquery.tokeninput.js.

I had to grab a new one from the Github, now everything works!